# operator+ won't recognize types

Tags: c++

I'm facing a weird problem. I have a stack of Literals, which contains Integers, Doubles, Rationnals, etc. I have defined operator+ to be able to do Double+Integer, Integer+Integer, etc.
But when I do :

```
Litteral& pop1 = stack.top();
stack.pop();
Litteral& pop2 = stack.top();
stack.pop();
Litteral& toAdd = (*pop1.clone() + *pop2.clone());
```

I get :

> no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Litteral' and 'Litteral')
>            Litteral& toAdd = (*pop1.clone() + *pop2.clone());

It does not recognize the types, even with clone(). And my operator+ are virtual.
Here's how I defined operator+ :

```
class Integer;

class Litteral {
public:
    virtual QString toString () const = 0;
    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
    virtual Litteral * clone() const = 0;
    virtual Litteral& operator+(const Integer& l) = 0;
};
class Integer: public Litteral {
    friend class LitteralManager;
    int value;
public:
    ...
    virtual Integer& operator+(const Integer& e);
    Integer* clone() const;
};
```

Here's clone() because I use the factory design pattern:

```
Integer* Integer::clone() const {
    return new Integer(*this);
}
```

Does anyone have a clue ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow. You have so many errors in your code. I suggest re-starting from scratch, maybe with something simpler.

Comment: You have `operator+` that takes `Litteral` and `Integer`. There's none that takes `Litteral` on both sides.

Comment: Besides, your program (once it compiles) would exhibit undefined behavior. You take a reference to `top()` element, then immediately destroy that element with `pop()`, then proceed to use the now-dangling reference.

Comment: Sorry, forgot one "Entier" (I'm translating everything from french). It means "Integer". And the thing is that I don't want them to act with Litteral, but with Integer. Operator+ in my Integer class takes two Integer, right ? Also, I remove it from the stack but I have a factory that is storing everything. That means my stack contains only references. So when I pop, I don't delete.

Answer (score 4):

There are many things wrong with this line:

```
Litteral& toAdd = (*pop1.clone() + *pop2.clone());
```

- You are leaking memory immediately. `clone()` allocates memory, you are not holding onto the pointer anywhere, so you can't ever `delete` it.
- `operator+` should create a new object, you have it returning a reference - but what would it be returning a reference to? That suggests it's modifying the left-hand argument, which would be very surprising to users if `a + b` modified `a`...
- Your `operator+` is defined to take a right-hand argument of `Integer const&`. But `*pop2.clone()` is a `Litteral` - there's no standard conversion from a base class to a derived class (after all, it might be a non-integer literal, right?). That's why there's no match for `operator+`. You'd have to change the signature of your function. This is the literal (ha!) answer to your question.
- The word literal only has one t in it.

---

Also this is bad:

```
Litteral& pop1 = stack.top();
stack.pop();
```

You're holding a dangling reference - the literal that was on top of the stack is destroyed by `pop()`. Any subsequent usage of `pop1` will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I'm leaking memory. Didn't see it, thanks. operator+ returns a reference because it calls a factory, which creates the new object, and return the reference. Also, I am using clone() to return an Integer. Yes an Integer is a Litteral, but the type of the object returned with clone() is an Integer. So why is it a Litteral? And yes there's two t because the code I'm writing is in French. I translated Entier into Integer but I did not do it for Litteral, sorry.

Comment: As of the stack, I don't use the stl stack but a personal one, that contains pointers, not the objects (they are stored in a sort of factory). When I pop(), I don't delete the object, I just remove it from the stack.

Comment: @Chuck It seems like your whole design is based on leaking memory. Maybe use a language with built-in garbage collection?

Comment: It's a `Literal` because the signature is `Literal* clone()`. The dynamic type of the returned object is `Integer*`, but it's still a `Literal*`.

Comment: @Barry So : `Integer * Integer ::clone() const {
    return new Integer (*this);
}` That returns a Litteral* instead of an Integer ?

Comment: @Chuck If you called it on an `Integer*`, it would return an `Integer*`. But you're calling it on a `Literal*`, so it returns a `Literal*`.